# JQuery borrar select dinamico

Tags: jquery

tengo un select dinamico con ajax que va creando selects con categorias. Estoy intentando hacer que cuando un slecet este seleccionado en 'seleccione' los que hay por delante de el se borren. Con este codigo cuando pongo a seleccione el segundo select me borra todos menos el primero.

```
<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list">
  <option value="seleccione">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="agricultor">A</option>
  <option value="viveristas">B</option>
</select>

<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list">
 <option value="seleccione">Seleccionar</option>
 <option value="frutos-secos">A.A</option>
 <option value="olivos">A.B</option>
</select>

<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list">
 <option value="seleccione">Seleccionar</option>
 <option value="arbequina">A.A.A</option>
 <option value="arbosana">A.A.B</option>
 <option value="koronieki">A.A.C</option>
</select>
```

El JQuery es:

```
if(s == 'seleccione'){
    jQuery('.selector-list').nextUntil().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer tu validación en el evento onchange donde utilices not para excluir el selector de donde se generó el evento y sustituir el html del resto de los selectores.

```
$(".selector-list").change(function(){
    $(".selector-list").not($(this)).html('<option value="seleccione">Seleccionar</option>');
});
```